# Compiling qt creator with Qt 5.4.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.1)

Tags: qt, makefile, mingw, qmake

When I build a qt creator in linux I don't have any problems.

But when I try to build the qt creator from source with `Qt 5.4.1` for `Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.1)`. I have problem with `lrelease` path

Compile Output:

> C:/Qt/Qt5.4.0/Tools/mingw491_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
>   mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory
>   'C:/src/qt-creator/build-qtcreator-Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/share/qtcreator/translations'
>   /C/Qt/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/bin/lrelease
>   C:/src/qt-creator/qt-creator/share/qtcreator/translations/qtcreator_cs.ts
>   -qm qtcreator_cs.qm /usr/bin/sh: /C/Qt/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/bin/lrelease: No such file or directory
>
> Makefile.Debug:161: recipe for target 'qtcreator_cs.qm' failed
>   mingw32-make[3]: *** [qtcreator_cs.qm] Error 127

I don't know why there are use unix way path `/C/Qt/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32.`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: krasotka, I gave an answer earlier but it was totally wrong, I deleted my answer maybe somebody else can help you out now that it's marked unanswered. I didn't even read the question right.

Answer (score 0):

You have partially answered the question yourself.

The path to `lrelease.exe` is not correct and it is used in `translations.pro`.

If you replace `$$LRELEASE` in command with actual lrelease path you should get through the compilation. However after this I got `0xc0000022` error with the latest version from git, I am not sure we are supposed to change anything really....